# Filling values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, data-transform

How to fill NAs with both the previous and next values separated by a comma in pandas.

For example:

I have

```
 1
 2
 4
 6 
NA 
 8 
 9
 5
```

.

Output:

```
 1 
 2 
 4
 6
 6,8
 8
 9
 5.
```

How is this possible in pandas?

Comment: Hint: create a series combining `ffill` and `bfill`, then `fillna` your original series with your created one.

Comment: Is it possible to do both in one go or should I do ffill first, then bfill and combine them??

Comment: Why would you want a `6,8` in a row, that ruins the dtype of the column, would it better to have 6 and 8 in separate rows and have the column dtype `int`

Comment: @Kenan that is a good question.  However, maybe the numerals we see are only part of OPs mcve and in their actual data set, they have strings.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) and [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html), then fill `NaN` value with [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s.fillna(s.ffill().astype(str).str.cat(s.bfill().astype(str),','))

0      1
1      2
2      4
3      6
4    6,8
5      8
6      9
7      5
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: great answer (-: